# Convert the integer MAC address returned by SendARP to a string

Tags: c

I have been trying to convert a decimal to a Mac address, I use the SendArp function to get the mac address and then from there I don't know what to do with the numbers any help? This is what I have done so far :

```
char * getMac(int IP)
{
    char *Mac_Addr = (char*)calloc(sizeof(char*), 1024);
    unsigned long DestMacAddr[2] = { 0 };
    unsigned long PhysicalLength = 6;

    int error = SendARP(htonl(IP), htonl(htonl(inet_addr("127.0.0.1"))), &DestMacAddr, &PhysicalLength);

    return error == NO_ERROR? Mac_Addr: "";
}
```

Comment: You don't know what to do with the numbers?  What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: I mean the contents of DestMacAddr I have no idea how to convert from decimal to ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Comment: The documentation shows exactly how to do it:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366358(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Wow thanks I didn't think to look there